# datetime.fromtimestamp TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, utc, epoch

I'm trying to convert epoch (unixtime) to datetime format (UTC) and have the code to do so;

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
vmmR817['datetime_new_utc']=datetime.fromtimestamp(vmmR817['epoch'],timezone.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
datetime.fromtimestamp(1563915600,timezone.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

The code works fine for individual epoch (1563915600), but not on the full series (vmmR817['epoch']) from a dataframe. It is returning the following error

> TypeError: cannot convert the series to

Df looks like:

[image]

Time series is running from :

```
datetime.fromtimestamp(1525039200,timezone.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
Out[93]: '2018-04-29 22:00:00'
```

to

```
datetime.fromtimestamp(1563915600,timezone.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
Out[92]: '2019-07-23 21:00:00'
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: by the way, there is a `datetime.utcfromtimestamp` - no need to set UTC as timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`datetime.fromtimestamp` expects a scalar input; but you are passing a pandas series (a column from a dataframe). That won't work. Simply use `pd.to_datetime` to convert the whole column:

```
import pandas as pd
# example df:
df = pd.DataFrame({'epoch': [1563915600]})
# convert the epoch column:
df['epoch'] = pd.to_datetime(df['epoch'], unit='s')
# 0   2019-07-23 21:00:00
# Name: t, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Works fine thanks! In addition, I make it timezone aware using `df['datetime_utc'] = pd.to_datetime(df['epoch'], unit='s', utc=True)`

Comment: @JelleH: alright, just make sure your timestamps refer to UTC in the first place ;-)